# Python virtualenvs bin folder does not have Python

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, interpreter

I created a new virtual environment by using Ubuntu windows version. Here you can see from photos,

[image: virtual environment]

But in Pycharm, it does not shown as python interpreter.

[image: pycharm]

There is no file in bin folder. I have to select Python from there but i could not figure it out.

I tried to deactivate my virtual environment : sses and try again from pycharm but still not working.
Thank you for your comments from now.

Comment: just check your venv path and then provide the path in pycharm

Comment: you could issue the command  whereis python to find where the python executable is

Comment: You're apparently using PyCharm from Windows but created the env from wsl. I don't think pycharm supports that, [it has a special wsl interpreter case](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) and notes "with WSL you cannot create virtual environments".

Comment: Go to: *File/Settings/Project/Python Interpreter/*. If you don't have a project interpreter, click on a settings icon and Add... You can create a new Virtual Environment with a path to Python base interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Pycharm Pro version. It has a WHL option in interpreters. Solved. Thanks for the responses :)

Answer (score 0):

*(a solution relevant to the title but not the question)*

To be able to use *virtual environment* in PyCharm, you must have *virtualenv* installed on your system. Otherwise, PyCharm will tell you that it could not find '/bin/python'.

In Ubuntu, installing *virtual environment* is as simple as

`sudo apt install python3-virtualenv`

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here with the Google search "venv missing bin folder" so this is tightly related to the question but potentially a bit different.

In my case, I had previously created a PyCharm project using virtual env and I wanted to reconsume that project.

PyCharm however did not create a bin folder, it instead put the python.exe binary instead in scripts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9wKc.png)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is wrong with your env, but python "now" comes with their own embedded virtual environment.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

You can use it with `python -m venv <path>`, and activate with `<path>/bin/activate`.

Answer (score -2):

try adding environment variables to path or try reinstalling python.